# DynamoDB Sort Key in CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml

I am honestly at a loss as to why this wont deploy. When I remove the sortKey from the AttributeDefinitions and Key Schema it deploys, when I add them in as shown below it fails to deploy.

```
  DepartmentsTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: Departments
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: sortKey
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: id
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: sortKey
          KeyType: RANGE
      ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

Comment: What is the error message that it shows you when it fails to deploy?

Comment: Are you creating a stack or updating an existing stack (and existing table)?

Comment: Am updating an existing stack

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are trying to modify the key schema of an existing DynamoDB table via a CloudFormation update. This will not work. You cannot change the key schema of an existing table.

Instead, you will have to create a new table and then migrate the old table's data.